# GUI install Visual Studio Code .deb file in Ubuntu 20.04 keeps loading forever

Tags: software-installation, software-center, gui, deb, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to install any .deb file using GUI in Ubuntu 20.04 it just keeps loading forever in the Ubuntu Software tab. When I open the Software app after searching for "vscode" in it, it keeps loading forever the same way as in the below screen animation.

[image]

Comment: In your heading & description you mention Ubuntu 20.04.1, so why did you tag Ubuntu 12.04 ?  How does it relate?  Is that where the .deb files are coming from?  (I'd not expect a lot of 12.04 deb files to be installable due to changes since 2012).  Please clarify.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/) will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks, @guiverc , I'm trying to install vscode using gui but it is loading only.

Comment: vscode is already installable through the Software app in Ubuntu 20.04 without any .deb file. Search in the Software app for "visual studio code".

Comment: @karel when I try to open Software app in ```Ubuntu 20.04.1``` and after searching ```vscode``` in it, it's loading in same way as before. although my internet connection is of mbps speed.

Comment: is ```Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS``` has of bug ?